# two styles in biblatex with textcite, author (year) and (author, year)

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` with the following commands, which produce Author (year) type citation using `\textcite{}` command. However, I have some places where I need (Author, year) type citation. How can I do this? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

%This part is for citation style textcite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifboolexpr{ ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
                  test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} ) or
                ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
                  test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} ) }
     {\usebibmacro{textcite}}
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{% Apply citation link to bibmacro output
        \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}% Prevent nested hyperlinks
        \usebibmacro{textcite}%
        \ifbool{cbx:parens}{\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}{}}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}{\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}{}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
```

Comment: You can just use `\parencite` instead of `\cite`.

Comment: That does not yield what I want. I want Author, year in some places and Author (year) in others. Sorry its not a matter of whole parenthesis, rather, a comma as separator, not parenthesis.

Comment: You should update your question and clarify what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `authoryear` citation style, `\parencite` uses the macro `\nameyeardelim` to store what should go between the name and the year in the citation.

In [`authoryear.cbx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), the cite command `\parencite` is defined in the following way:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

And in [`biblatex.def`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), we find

```
\newcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
```

You could define your own cite command to put a comma between the author and the year and put everything in parantheses, e.g. by redefining `\nameyeardelim`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myparencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\def\nameyeardelim{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \def\nameyeardelim{\addspace}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

By changing `\nameyeardelim` back to simply `\addspace` after printing this citation, we avoid interference with other citations.

Using the [`filecontents`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents) package to produce a full example, this yields

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%This part is for citation style textcite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifboolexpr{ ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
                  test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} ) or
                ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
                  test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} ) }
     {\usebibmacro{textcite}}
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{% Apply citation link to bibmacro output
        \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}% Prevent nested hyperlinks
        \usebibmacro{textcite}%
        \ifbool{cbx:parens}{\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}{}}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}{\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}{}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\myparencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\def\nameyeardelim{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \def\nameyeardelim{\addspace}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{test,
  title={something},
  author={someone},
  journal={some journal},
  year={2013}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\textcite{test}
\parencite{test}
\myparencite{test}
\textcite{test}
\end{document}
```

And this results in

[image: compiled pdf]

so `\myparencite{test}` puts a comma between the author and the year.